# DynamicClass and DynamicLinq.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dynamic-linq, dynamic-class

I have a class that I created dynamically. I dynamically create the properties of this class and add value to these properties. So far there is no problem. However, when I create a list of this class and make queries using "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq", I get an error. How can I create a dynamic class and query a list of this class type with "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq"? What's the best way to do this?

I have shared a similar code below. This code is giving an error. Can you guide me? Or I would be glad if there are examples you can share.

Error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The binary operator GreaterThan is not defined for the types' System.Object 'and' System.Int32 '.'

```
        List<DynamicClass> schemas = new List<DynamicClass>();

        foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(1,100))
        {
            Type schemaType = null;
            var props = new List<DynamicProperty>();

            props.Add(new DynamicProperty("Id", typeof(long)));
            props.Add(new DynamicProperty("Name", typeof(string)));
            props.Add(new DynamicProperty("Birthday", typeof(DateTime)));
            props.Add(new DynamicProperty("Age", typeof(int)));

            DynamicClass schemaClass = null;
            schemaType = DynamicClassFactory.CreateType(props);
            schemaClass = Activator.CreateInstance(schemaType) as DynamicClass;

            schemaClass.SetDynamicPropertyValue("Id", item);
            schemaClass.SetDynamicPropertyValue("Name", "Serkan");
            schemaClass.SetDynamicPropertyValue("Birthday", DateTime.Now.AddDays(item));
            schemaClass.SetDynamicPropertyValue("Age", DateTime.Now.Day + item);

            schemas.Add(schemaClass);
        }

        var query = schemas.AsQueryable().Where("(Id > @0 and Id < @1) or Id == @2", 10, 30, 31).OrderBy("Id"); // I'm getting the error I mentioned here
        var results = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    IList CreateListFor(object obj)
    {
        Type t = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(obj.GetType());
        return (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    }

    IList CreateListFor(Type t)
    {
        Type lt = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t);
        return (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(lt);
    }

    void Test()
    {
        var props = new List<DynamicProperty>();

        props.Add(new DynamicProperty("Id", typeof(int)));
        props.Add(new DynamicProperty("Name", typeof(string)));
        props.Add(new DynamicProperty("Birthday", typeof(DateTime)));
        props.Add(new DynamicProperty("Age", typeof(int)));

        var schemaType = DynamicClassFactory.CreateType(props);

        var schemas = CreateListFor(schemaType);

        foreach (var itemx in Enumerable.Range(1, 100))
        {
            var schemaClass = Activator.CreateInstance(schemaType) as DynamicClass;

            schemaClass.SetDynamicPropertyValue("Id", itemx);

            schemaClass.SetDynamicPropertyValue("Name", "Serkan");

            schemaClass.SetDynamicPropertyValue("Birthday", DateTime.Now.AddDays(itemx));

            schemaClass.SetDynamicPropertyValue("Age", DateTime.Now.Day + itemx);

            schemas.Add(schemaClass);
        }

        var query = schemas.AsQueryable();
        var results = query.Where("(Id > @0 and Id < @1) or Id == @2", 10, 30, 31); // I'm getting the error I mentioned here
    }
```